# In App Messaging not working Due to "Service Fetch Error"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

We just implemented in app messaging, in our existing application on Play Store. But, the in app messaging is not working, not showing any popup, So, we tried to use updated JSON, still there is no improvement and mentioned logs are showing which has errors "Service Fetch Error".

Please help.

Implementations:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.1'
```

Logs:

```
2021-09-27 12:04:06.759 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: went foreground
2021-09-27 12:04:06.770 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Display: Binding to activity: DashBoardActivity
2021-09-27 12:04:06.771 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: Setting display event component
2021-09-27 12:04:06.920 14919-14971/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: Forcing fetch from service rather than cache. Test Device: false | App Fresh Install: true
2021-09-27 12:04:06.931 14919-14971/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: Recoverable exception while reading cache: /data/user/0/com.hubhopper/files/fiam_impressions_store_file (No such file or directory)
2021-09-27 12:04:07.211 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Installation ID dA_tOxrhRJGCYmjyGXjM9A
2021-09-27 12:04:07.471 14919-15020/com.hubhopper W/FIAM.Headless: Service fetch error: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
2021-09-27 12:07:54.178 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Display: Unbinding from activity: DashBoardActivity
2021-09-27 12:07:54.178 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: Removing display event component
2021-09-27 12:07:57.064 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: went foreground
2021-09-27 12:07:57.066 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Display: Binding to activity: DashBoardActivity
2021-09-27 12:07:57.066 14919-14919/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: Setting display event component
2021-09-27 12:07:57.071 14919-14971/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: Forcing fetch from service rather than cache. Test Device: false | App Fresh Install: true
2021-09-27 12:07:57.074 14919-14971/com.hubhopper I/FIAM.Headless: Recoverable exception while reading cache: /data/user/0/com.hubhopper/files/fiam_impressions_store_file (No such file or directory)
2021-09-27 12:07:57.252 14919-16103/com.hubhopper W/FIAM.Headless: Service fetch error: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.
```

It's also not working using with firebase-BOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the guidance, our api key on Google Cloud credentials is not working for firebase installations from starting.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-installations/API_KEY_RESTRICTIONS.md

Now, in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/metrics
metrics we are getting 200 and in app messaging is also working fine.

So, if you are facing "Firebase Installations Service is unavailable" error then update the google_services.json file by making new credentials on google cloud OR restrict the firebase installations in the current key you are using for android.

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean, *Restrict the installations*? Applications based restrictions or Apis based restrictions? Thanks.

Comment: there is an option in credentials in google cloud console under the application to restrict the installations for current key.